# How to use Mobile Phone as USB especially Nokia S-60 series

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, samsung-mobile

I am working on a project in Java Netbeans where I am using mobile phone **Nokia E-72** (that is connected to computer via data cable) and I am sending and receiving messages from/to computer through the mobile phone.

But the problem is that mostly phones automatically install the specific device driver (i.e mobile suit) in the computer as soon as the mobile is connected to the computer whereas **I need to use the mobile phone as a USB** in my code as the Port gets busy and consumed by the respective mobile suit/driver if the mobile is not connected as a USB.

**Samsung Galaxy S2** comes with a built in TP-Link kind of software because of which when I connect the S2 with computer I get an option to connect the mobile with Samsung Suit i.e. Kies or connect as a USB.

I want to know how to get this same thing for any other mobile as well?

Comment: Have you read [this wiki page](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_USB_cable_connection_in_Java_ME)?